# axios not catching error

Tags: express, react-redux, axios

Axios is not catching a "Duplicate entry for email" error. My axios function is in my action creator (redux) that sends post to my express server. Here is the call

```
axios.post(api + '/api/register', { user })
  .then(res => {
      dispatch(success(user));
      dispatch({ type: ADD_USER, payload: res.data.data });
  })
  .catch(error => {
      alert('error');
      // dispatch({ type: ADD_TOAST, payload: error.response.data });
  });
```

I get no alert and there's no response (res) ? But on my server I console log for errors showing me the "Error: duplicate entry" message. Is this unique to the error or is there a bug in my code?

** edit w/ express file

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {

  let firstname = req.body.user.firstname;
  let lastname = req.body.user.lastname;
  let email = req.body.user.email;
  let username = req.body.user.username;
  let password = req.body.user.password;

  bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function(err, hash) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Could not hash password: ' + err);
    } else {
        // insert into users with hash then profiles
        database.query('INSERT INTO Users (ID, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, CreateDate) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)', [firstname, lastname, email, hash], function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                // get inserted id && insert into profiles
                let userID = result.insertId;

                database.query('INSERT INTO Profiles(ID, UserID, Photo, Bio) VALUES (NULL, ?, NULL, NULL)', [userID], function(err, result) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log('We could not create your profile' + err);
                    } else {
                        let data = {
                            firstname: firstname,
                            lastname: lastname,
                            email: email,
                            photo: null
                        }

                        res.json({ data });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Is your server throwing an actual error? Or is it just catching and logging?

Comment: As no code is being sent it seems it's just catching and logging. Maybe i should send a .status(500) in my server file?

Comment: Can you show us some of the express code?

Comment: sure ill edit into question

Comment: Is that your `/api/register` endpoint?

Comment: yes it is (just for SO comment minimum lol)

Comment: Okay, so you're doing `if(err) { … }`. I would recommend doing `res.status(400)` or something. Then you can check that status in your client-side `then`. If the status is anything other than a successful 200, then you can throw an error on the client side to pass it to the `catch` handler.

Comment: i tried to put res.status(400) in the if(err) { ... } and i am getting the same result. Should i get rid of the if (err) and just do if(result) { ... } res.status(400, { message }

Comment: Okay, but now on the client-side request, you need to check if the status is 400. If it is, throw an error in the then, which you can catch in catch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to use

> **return**

statement in your axios function

like this:

```
async function register (data) {
  return axios.post(api + '/api/register', data)
  .then(res => {
    dispatch(success(user));
    dispatch({ type: ADD_USER, payload: res.data.data });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    alert('error');
    // dispatch({ type: ADD_TOAST, payload: error.response.data });
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify from console.log(error) to console.log(error.response) in catch.

```
axios.post('/formulas/create', {
name: "",
parts: "" }).then(response => { 
console.log(response) }) .catch(error => {console.log(error.response)});
```

Comment: The catch handler isn't even being executed. Why would this fix the underlying problem?